# Oracle - return only the first row for each product

Tags: sql, oracle

In the first SELECT statement, the report grabs inv details for all products with shipment activity.  There is then a UNION that connect another SELECT statement to grab products without activity from the last calendar year.

However, the records that are returned in the second SELECT statement have multiple header_id’s and therefore multiple lines… instead of single lines like the first SELECT statement.  Do you know how to pull only the first header_id of each record in the second SELECT statement?

Code and example result set below.  In data, product #7 should only list the row for header_id 1372288 which is the last ID entered into the DB.

[image]

```
select 3 sort_key, header_Id,location_id,nlasinv.product,
                                   start_inv,produced produced_inv,stored,from_stock,shipped,
                                   (start_inv + produced + stored) - (from_stock + shipped) end_inv,nlas_ops_mtd_prodsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19'), nlas_ops_mtd_shipsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19'),nlas_ops_ytd_prodsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19'), nlas_ops_ytd_shipsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19')
                                   from nlas_header inv,
                                     nlas_inventory nlasinv
                                   where nlasinv.header_id = 1372168   
                                   and inv.id = nlasinv.header_id
    union 
    select distinct
       3 sort_key,header_Id,location_id,nlasinv.product,
       start_inv,produced produced_inv,stored,from_stock,shipped,
                                   (start_inv + produced + stored) - (from_stock + shipped) end_inv,nlas_ops_mtd_prodsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19'),
       nlas_ops_mtd_shipsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19'),nlas_ops_ytd_prodsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19'),
       nlas_ops_ytd_shipsize(111,nlasinv.product,'31-DEC-19')
       from
         nlas_inventory nlasinv,
         nlas_header hdr
         where
         nlasinv.header_id = hdr.id
         and hdr.location_id = 409
         and hdr.observation_date >= trunc(to_date('31-DEC-19','dd-mon-rr'),'year') 
         and nlasinv.product not in
         (select distinct product from
           nlas_header h,
           nlas_inventory i
           where i.header_id = 1372168) 
order by product, header_id des
```

c

Comment: How do you define "the first row"? The minimal date, value, other?

Comment: The "first row" would be the row with the highest header_id... which amounts to the most recent record.

Comment: Then Gordon's answer is correct. In his answer `t` represents the whole query you have (except for the last `ORDER BY` clause that should be placed after the solution (at the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your query has to do with the "table" data that you show.  But you seem to want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by product order by header_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If that query is being used to generate the data, then just wrap it in a CTE.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I want to be sure I understand... do I wrap my entire statement using the method that Gordon listed?  To simplify my query:  select header_Id,product,start_inv,produced,stored,from_stock,shipped
   from 
     nlas_header inv,
     nlas_inventory nlasinv
   where inv.id = nlasinv.header_id
union 
select header_Id,product,start_inv,produced,stored,from_stock,shipped
   from
     nlas_inventory nlasinv,
     nlas_header hdr
     where nlasinv.header_id = hdr.id
     and hdr.observation_date >= '01-DEC-19' 
order by product, header_id desc

Comment: @user2470781 . . . `with t as (<your query here>) <the above query>`.

Comment: You nailed it Gordon!  I was able to return the rows I was expecting.  Thanks for your help, and thanks to Impaler for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished by adding a self join in your where clause

```
and hdr.header_id = (
   select max(hdr2.header_id) 
   from nlas_header hdr2 
   where hdr2.location_id = hdr.location_id 
   and hdr2.product_id = hdr.product_id)
```